# WebDriver with TestNg

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can any body post `WebDriver` format code with `TestNg` framework?

Not a single class, I need 2 or more class with using WebDriver driver without any error in second class. I'm presently unable to properly execute second class code due to driver.

My problem is that `nullpointer` exception is coming if I use more than 2 classes in testng.

I followed this steps:

**1)** Create First class with private WebDriver drive & with annotation `@BeforeTest` with `driver=new FirefoxDriver()`

**2)** The second class uses another activity by using driver.

But second class gives `nullpointer` exception.

Comment: plz post code with  two class with driver code not syso

Comment: Hi, I just edited your question and tried to improve the general format of it. Try to understand the changes and apply them in your future questions. Be sure to ask when in doubt. Report: Text format and corrections.